# why my schedule function on python is not working with webbrowser in python?

Tags: python, schedule

So i am making a program where a user can join a google meeting automatically on a specific time given by the user. I am using schedule module for setting the time of the meeting, but i can't understand why my main function isn't obeying the given time. I am new in python.

here's my code:

```
import datetime
import schedule
import pyautogui
import time
import webbrowser

def autoconnect(link):
    webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com")
    x = 10
    time.sleep(x)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'l')
    pyautogui.write(link, interval=0.04)
    pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
    x = 5
    time.sleep(x)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'e')
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'd')
    x = 3
    time.sleep(x)
    pyautogui.click(1348,606)


url = input('url: ')

clock =  input("Schedule?: ")

schedule.every().day.at(clock).do(autoconnect(url))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

also please suggest how i can make it efficient and better.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `.do(autoconnect(url))`, that runs the function immediately, and then passes the return value (which is `None`) to the scheduler.  You need

```
schedule.every().day.at(clock).do(autoconnect,link=url)
```

By the way, Google has APIs to control every aspect of their offerings.  That has to be a better solution than the hackery you're doing here.  If they change their web page at all, or if your window is on a different screen, your clicks will stop working.